# Students not engaged at all - despite the efforts of their instructor

Tags: evaluation

My institution moved all courses online this term. I spent a great amount of efforts:

- Pre-recording 3 hours of lectures (accompanied by 2% weekly asynchronous quizzes on Moodle)
- Holding two 1.5 hours of live Q&A sessions weekly on Zoom

However, the attendance of the Q&A sessions have been embarrassingly low (less than 30 out of 320 students). Although students attempt to follow the weekly lecture videos, the vast majority of them only do so about 1 or 2 days before the weekly quizzes are due.

Nonetheless, students simply just complain about the workload in general (not just because of this course, but for the accumulated required screen time from all other courses).

The end-or-semester course evaluation will start soon. While I am confident that I have done all I could have creating quality learning materials, I am pessimistic about that the majority of students might just put very negative comments just because they are not happy about all courses moved online, not because of my teaching quality.

Is this something I shall expect in this very difficulty time? To me, it is just unfair to receive evaluation from students who mostly do not even engage in the content in the first place.

Let me know how you folks think?

Comment: There isn't really an answerable question here. Needs a rewrite.

Comment: And a zoom session with more than 30 students seems pretty unmanageable. They probably have a right to be frustrated.

Comment: @Buffy  Managing Zoom sessions with more than 30 students requires planning, discipline, and (ideally) more than one human being running the show—You can't just pretend to be standing in front of a lecture hall—but it's definitely doable.

Comment: @JeffE, but much harder for a question/answer session where you can only respond to one person at a time. Why would the come if they are pretty certain their own concerns can't be met. And the 30 that do show up may well be those who need it least. The system described is broken.

Comment: @Buffy "you can only respond to one person at a time" -- I am curious, how is this aspect different in a live session?

Comment: @GoodDeeds not much different actually. A room with 320 students is not very conducive to questions. But the OP doesn't say how many TAs might be involved to be able to provide meaningfully sized sessions. However, zoom and the equivalent are much less effective than face to face in general. Easier to get lost, distracted, bored, etc.

Comment: If attendance for office hours is an issue, you may consider the timing of your office hours.  Ask yourself when you think your students are doing their work, and plan your office hours with this in mind when possible.  Constant reminders about office hours, and what they are for is a good way to boost attendance.  

Expecting your students to watch 3 hours of lecture video is just not reasonable for most college students - regardless of topic - in my opinion.  This may be the same time as you spend face-to-face, but their level of interaction is much different.

Comment: @Buffy Larger classes call for different types of interaction than smaller classes. Not _worse_, just _different_. If you walk into a class of 100 expecting to do the same thing you did with 20—or vice versa!—you're going to be disappointed.

Comment: My impression during the last semester was that students don't like prerecorded lectures and Q&A sessions, but rather prefer to have live lectures with the possibility to interact directly.

Comment: Have you asked the students what would be good for them?

Comment: @Buffy During the last semester I had Zoom sessions with around 60-70 students. It's manageable and we had quite lively interactions. Indeed it requires planning and flexibility.

Comment: As a student: although I appreciate your efforts, you'd immediately lost me at the 3-hour-lecture point. For many students, it is extremely hard to concentrate at something like that on the screen, even if it is not pre-recorded but live. Other teachers probably do the same and I cannot tell you how exhausting it is. Think about hands-on assignments, very good written material (for many students they are much easier to digest than oral lectures anyway), etc. Whatever that does not require looking at someone talking at the screen for hours.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really answer the question, which seems to assume (and presents as the major issue) that you get bad feedback which may not be true (the students still have what the other lecturers do to compare, so I wouldn't assume they use your specific feedback to complain about the general situation).

I wonder if you had to do pre-recorded lectures. We do (and record) lectures in real time with students present online, which has the advantage that students can ask specific questions on issues that may affect their understanding of what follows when they arise. (I do realise that this could be problematic with 320 students, however it may work in your favour that only a small number of them appear to be willing to interact.) Surely it makes things somewhat more lively.

One thing you could do is to have online surveys about their satisfaction, how they perceive the course, what they like, and what can be improved. You don't seem to have a clear idea on how students use and perceive your course, and you could do something to improve your knowledge on this.

To some extent online teaching encourages students to hide and not participate and do things last minute. However I'd think something more can be done to encourage interaction. I also have a written questions and comments forum, which is well used (if mostly of course by a minority of active students, but that's how these things always are and were before the age of Covid) on top of being available for online Q&A.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you have a specific answerable question here, but here are some things I did to improve my online teaching in the current environment:

1. Prior to the start of the semester I send out a survey to everyone registered for the class, asking about their preferences for course delivery methods. I gave a few options like a) live (synchronous) lecture sessions, b) pre-recorded (asynchronous) lecture videos, c) live Q&A / recitation sessions on Webex.  There was a very strong preference among the students (by 2:1 margin) for certain modalities versus others.  I started the first few weeks of the class using the method preferred by the students
2. After about three weeks of the class, I send another survey, asking how they liked the class delivery.  I thought they might change their minds after actually seeing how their choices really worked out.  Majority of the class liked format.  Several students did not like the format, but they offered helpful suggestions on how to improve and I incorporated those (e.g. switching from one video conferencing system to another one, changes to homework assignments).
3. 10% of the grade in the class is based on class participation.  Students get class participation points for things like a) attending live recitation sessions, b) attending office hours, c) posting on the class discussion board, etc.  This gave them incentives to stay engaged with the material, even though the class was online.